# Making domdocument img search more lightweight

Tags: php, domdocument, getimagesize

This grabs all images from a page, and is supposed to check if image has more width and height than 200. if so, grab the first of it. But its an expensive process, and im wondering if there are more lightweight approaches to this than using getimagesize. Does anyone know of a different approach without the use of external services like YQL etc?

```
if($ogimage!=''|| !empty($ogimage)){
    $arrimg = $ogimage;
} else {
    $imgarr = array();
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    $arrimg_push = $img->getAttribute('src');
    array_push($imgarr, $arrimg_push);
}
    $i=0;
    foreach($imgarr as $img){
     list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($img);
        if($width > 200 && $height > 200){
            if($i > 0){
            $arrimg = $img;
            $i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is count of image in document?

Comment: It varies, it scrapes urls provided by users. so it can be 0 - 1000 depending on the website.

Comment: This is clearly to spending long time to execute of code because target images is in remote server!

Comment: good point! maybe ill just do a fancy loading animation or something in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageMagick's [pingImage or pingImageFile](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/imagick.pingimage.php) will read as little of the image file as possible to get the basic attributes, which can then be accessed using `getImageWidth` and `getImageHeight`.